# QThread Basic use in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I've got a c++ code including GUI, in which I need to run a time consuming loop for optimization.

```
class OptimizationAlgorith(data *data);
{
private:
    var var1;
    var var2;
public:
    method1();
    method2();
    ..
    timeConsumingMethod(data);
}
```

this need to be called in a GUI class like following:

```
    class QRegistration: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    data *m_data;
    QPushButton     *m_button_run;
    OptimizationAlgorithm *m_optimizationalgorithm;
    WorkerThread *m_workerThread;
    QThread *m_thread;
    ..
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_run_clicked();
    void registrationDone();
```

I need to move the `timeConsumingMethod` into a seperate thread than main thread, so that the GUI does not freez while `timeConsumingMethod`is running.
I have made a new class "WorkerThread" using the official documentation of Qt, which looks like:

```
class WorkerThread : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    WorkerThread(ApplicationData* data, QOptimizationAlgorithm * OptimizationAlgorithm);
    ~WorkerThread();

    public slots:
        void run(data* data);

signals:
    void finished();
    private slots:

private:
    OptimizationAlgorithm *m_OptimizationAlgorithm;
    ApplicationData *m_data;
}
```

How shoud I now implement my `run()`in `WorkerThread`? Can I simply write:

```
void WorkerThread::run(data *m_data)
{
    m_optimization.timeConsumingMethod(m_data);
    emit finished();
}
```

or do I have to copy the whole definition of `timeConsumingMethod` in `run()`? Why/Why not?

Comment: You don't need to reimplement `run` method if you are using a "worker" pattern. Try to read Qt documentation, there are perfect examples.

Comment: You don't have to copy whole definition of timeConsumingMethod, any code called inside run() will execute in the WorkerThread's thread, to proof that use QThread::currentThreadId() function to get thread id.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any explicit thread management, Qt already does it for you. Use `QtConcurrent::run` to do the work in a worker thread from the thread pool.

You should also decouple the controller that manages the work, and the UI. The knowledge of how to couple these objects should be separate from the objects themselves. This allows more flexibility in the design of the UI and the controller, and helps avoid several classes of errors that stem from accessing non-thread-safe methods from incorrect threads.

Complete example:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/threadwork-simple-40865259
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtConcurrent>

struct ApplicationData {};

struct OptimizationAlgorithm {
   void timeConsumingMethod(QSharedPointer<ApplicationData>) {
      QThread::sleep(3);
   }
};

class Controller : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QSharedPointer<ApplicationData> m_data{new ApplicationData};
   OptimizationAlgorithm m_algorithm;
public:
   Q_SLOT void run() {
      QtConcurrent::run([this]{
         emit busy();
         m_algorithm.timeConsumingMethod(m_data);
         emit finished();
      });
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void busy();
   Q_SIGNAL void finished();
};

class Registration : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QVBoxLayout m_layout{this};
   QLabel m_status{"Idle"};
   QPushButton m_run{"Run"};
public:
   Registration() {
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_status);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_run);
      connect(&m_run, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Registration::reqRun);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void reqRun();
   Q_SLOT void onBusy() { m_status.setText("Running"); }
   Q_SLOT void onFinished() { m_status.setText("Idle"); }
};

void setup(Registration *reg, Controller *ctl) {
   using Q = QObject;
   Q::connect(reg, &Registration::reqRun, ctl, &Controller::run);
   Q::connect(ctl, &Controller::busy, reg, &Registration::onBusy);
   Q::connect(ctl, &Controller::finished, reg, &Registration::onFinished);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   Controller ctl;
   Registration reg;
   setup(&reg, &ctl);
   reg.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```